# Creating a cloumn that sums up previous column entries based on criteria in different columns

Tags: r

Hi I want to create an experience variable from a dataframe looking similar to this:

```
ID    Year   Experience gained that year
1      2000      1
1      2001      3
1      2002      1
```

I am trying to do something similar to this:

```
NewDF <- DF %>% mutate(Cummulated_Exp = sum(DF[which(DF$ID == ID & DF$year < year),3]))`
```

resulting in

```
ID    Year   Experience gained that year      Cummulated_EXp
1      2000      1                                0
1      2001      3                                3
1      2002      1                                4
```

This wont work for a variety of reasons, likely something to do with the data i give to the `sum()` function as the ultimate error i always arrive at

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: your logic is not clear `DF$ID == ID & DF$year < year`. can you describe the logic

Comment: I want to add all the experience that occurred for the same unit (DF$ID == ID) in the previous years (DF$year < year). So I guess the output table is slightly wrong and the logic for the output presented would be (DF$year <= year) but same thing.

Comment: I think you want `DF %>% arrange(ID, Year) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Cum_Exp = cumsum(\`Experience gained that year\`))`

Comment: You need a `arrange(ID, Year) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Cumulated_Exp = cumsum(`Experience gained that year`)`

Comment: Thank you that solves it, not quite sure what went wrong but thanks!!

Comment: I've closed as a duplicate of "sum by group" - you just need to replace `sum` with `cumsum`. Two big misconceptions in your attempt: you want a sum for each `ID`, so you need `group_by(ID)`. The other big miss is that with `dplyr` you almost **never** need to use the data frame name inside the `dplyr` functions. Using `DF[which(DF$ID == ID & DF$year < year),3]` instead of just using column names will break groupings and often cause errors.